# What was Brawne's race?

Tags: hyperion-cantos

After reading all four books in the Hyperion Cantos, I wanted to know whether Lusians in general were white or black or unspecified--I know they were short and stocky because of the high gravity. The author generally goes into a lot of detail about various people's and worlds ethnic traits so I was wondering if I missed this about the Lusians.

Comment: Doesn't it occur to you that it's rather nonsensical to use "race" to talk about skin colour (which it isn't really - a strongly tanned "white" person can easily have darker skin that many "black" people) when discussing interstellar populations with significnatly differen physiques?

Comment: Not really because Simmons makes such a point of describing people's specific heritages and races throughout the series. I'm just keeping with his general orientation.

Answer (score 5):

She *appears* to be Caucasian. The main description of her...

> she's shorter than many others, but has "heavy layers of muscle"
>   (1.30). She also has "black curls [that] reached to her shoulders"
>   (1.30) and a mouth "wide and expressive to the point of being
>   sensuous, curled slightly at the corners in a slight smile which might
>   be cruel or merely playful" (1.30) According to the narrator, she
>   "might well be considered beautiful" (1.31). <sub><sup>[Schmoop](http://www.shmoop.com/hyperion/brawne-lamia.html)</sup></sub>

...doesn't mention her racial characteristics but there is a point in Hyperion where she uses a melanin pill to turn her skin black which implies that she was Caucasian (or at least non-black) beforehand:

> Instead of ’casting back to Lusus, I spent a few minutes checking the
>   plaza and side streets. **By this time the melanin pill I’d swallowed
>   had worked and I was a young black woman—or man, it was hard to tell
>   in my trendy red balloon jacket and polarized visor,** strolling idly
>   while taking pictures with my tourist imager.

Comment: The other Lusians mentioned (Kolchev and his wife) aren't described in any great detail.